# CodeIgniter: Remove index.php redirects to the wrong folder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried all solutions I found about removing `index.php` from the URL, but I still cannot make it work properly.

**Problem:**
the URL `http://localhost/rc/index.php/person/find` shows the correct page.
the URL `http://localhost/rc/person/find` shows the WAMP main page (without any image) like it redirects to the root's parent folder.

**my configuration:**
I created `.htaccess` is placed in my root directory (/www/rc/.htaccess) which contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Turn on MOD REWRITE engine
  RewriteEngine On

  #Remove index.php from the URL
  RewriteBase /rc/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

  #Also tried the following lines without success
  #RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If mod_rewrite is not installed, fire 404 error
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have also set `$config['index_page'] = '';` (in www/rc/application/config/config.php file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put your rule **before** CodeIgniter's main rule.

Replace your current code by this one (your htaccess has to be in `rc` folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /rc/

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/rc/index\.php/([^\s]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I pasted the code you have suggested. The result didn't change.
I am still localhost (wamp page without images) main page when I use the url `http://localhost/rc/person/find`

Comment: Does `http://localhost/rc/index.php/person/find` well redirect to `http://localhost/rc/person/find` ? Also, `http://localhost/rc/person/find` is internally rewritten to `/rc/index.php/person/find` so you must have another problem elsewhere

Comment: No! the `http://localhost/rc/index.php/person/find` is not redirected. It shows the correct response.
I also think that the problem comes from elsewhere, because if I click any project listed in the WAMP main page `(http://localhost/)`, I get the wrong URL. It shows only: `http://rc/` instead of `http://localhost/rc/`.
Is there a problem with Wamp then?

Comment: Are you sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled ? You can check it in your apache config file

Comment: In the file `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf`, I found the following line:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
It is NOT set as a comment.
Does this mean that **mod_rewrite** is enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by `it is set as a commented` ? You mean the line has a leading `#` ? If so, remove it then restart apache

Comment: No, there was no `#` leading the line.

Comment: You were right! before opening the file, I clicked on "rewrite_module" from the WAMP icon and I thought it didn't work. But I think it removed the `#` from the apache config file!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by Justin Iurman in the comment of the first answer:

> Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled ? You can check it in your apache config

This can be enabled in httpd.conf file or from the WAMP tray icon.

Comment: You can simply validate my answer in that case